# Why does the direction property not work on block level elements

Tags: html, css, direction

I want the hover functionality of the nav bar to extend the full height of the header parent element.

I believe this is currently not doing this because the anchor tag is an inline element.  If I add display: inline-block to the CSS for the ***header .nav a*** selector, this works as I want it to BUT then does not honour the direction property I set in the ***header .nav*** selector and reverses the order of the elements.

Can anyone tell me why this would be?

I have researched this and on the [MDN site for the direction CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) it says

> For the direction property to have any effect on inline-level
>   elements, the unicode-bidi property's value must be embed or override.

if i add the **unicode-bidi** CSS property:

1. with the embed value, nothing happens
2. with the bidi-override value, the words are reversed in place.

   [image: screenshot of navbar usingunicode-bidi]

Thanks for your patience, I am a noob at all this.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header {
  height: 7vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #D1C4E9;
  line-height: 7vh;
}
header .nav {
  margin-right: 3vw;
  direction: rtl;
}
header .nav a {
  //display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6A1B9A;
}
header .nav a:hover {
  background-color: #6A1B9A;
  color: #D1C4E9;
}
```

```html
<header>
  
  <div class='nav'>
    <a href='#'>Home</a>
    <a href='#'>Products</a>
    <a href='#'>Services</a>
    <a href='#'>About</a>
  </div>
  
</header>
```

Comment: If you set the `direction` to `rtl`, as per the MDN example you yourself gave, the reversal of the nav links is intended behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then does not honour the direction property I set in the header .nav selector and reverses the order of the elements.

This is the intended result when changing the direction and having `inline-block` elements. The order will get switched.

The behavior with text is not exactly the same and here the `unicode-bidi` play it roles. Basically when a browser will change the direction, it will not break down the text and change the order of each character. this will be done only if you change `unicode-bidi`

> **normal**
>
> The element does not open an additional level of embedding with respect to the bidirectional algorithm. For inline elements, implicit<sup>1</sup> reordering works across element boundaries.
>
> **bidi-override**
>
> This means that inside the element, reordering is strictly in sequence according to the 'direction' property; the **implicit<sup>1</sup> part** of the bidirectional algorithm **is ignored**.

Here is an example to better understand and to see the difference when having extra wrapper:

```css
span {
  border:1px solid;
}
div {
 margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="direction:rtl;">lorem ipsum text</div>

<div style="direction:rtl;">lorem <span>ipsum text</span></div>

<div style="direction:rtl;">lorem <span style="display:inline-block">ipsum text</span></div>

<div style="direction:rtl;unicode-bidi:bidi-override">lorem ipsum text</div>

<div style="direction:rtl;unicode-bidi:bidi-override">lorem <span>ipsum text</span></div>

<div style="direction:rtl;unicode-bidi:bidi-override">lorem <span style="display:inline-block">ipsum text</span></div>
```

> <sup>1</sup>The algorithm consists of an implicit part based on character properties, as well as explicit controls for embeddings and overrides. CSS 2.1 relies on this algorithm to achieve proper bidirectional rendering. The 'direction' and 'unicode-bidi' properties allow authors to specify how the elements and attributes of a document language map to this algorithm.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#direction

---

All the above is a bit complicated and the use of direction is not the way to go. You can either consider `text-align` with `inline-block`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header {
  height: 7vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #D1C4E9;
  line-height: 7vh;
}
header .nav {
  margin-right: 3vw;
  text-align:right;
}
header .nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6A1B9A;
}
header .nav a:hover {
  background-color: #6A1B9A;
  color: #D1C4E9;
}
```

```html
<header>
  
  <div class='nav'>
    <a href='#'>Home</a>
    <a href='#'>Products</a>
    <a href='#'>Services</a>
    <a href='#'>About</a>
  </div>
  
</header>
```

Or use flexbox to easily control alignment:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header {
  height: 7vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #D1C4E9;
  line-height: 7vh;
}
header .nav {
  margin-right: 3vw;
  text-align:right;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
header .nav a {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6A1B9A;
}
header .nav a:hover {
  background-color: #6A1B9A;
  color: #D1C4E9;
}
```

```html
<header>
  
  <div class='nav'>
    <a href='#'>Home</a>
    <a href='#'>Products</a>
    <a href='#'>Services</a>
    <a href='#'>About</a>
  </div>
  
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, @TemaniAfif.  that helped me understand it a lot better.  Cheers